# How to test if msg was send to GenServer process

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm running GenServer as a background job which is rescheduled each `interval` by `Process.send_after(self(), :work, @interval)`.

This job is started by Supervisor when Application starts.

It's working perfectly, but now I want to test if my GenServer module is really spawning new process each `interval`.

How can I test it?

*EDIT*

I found that `:sys.get_status(pid)` can be use to fetch some data about process, but I would really like to use something like `receive do ... end`

**EDIT 2**

`handle_info/2` function:

```
@impl true
def handle_info(:work, state) do
  do_smt()

  schedule_worker()

  {:noreply, state}
end
```

`schedule_worker/0` function:

```
defp schedule_worker do
  Process.send_after(self(), :work, @interval)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There's something missing in your message. From what you have posted we can understand that every `@interval` milliseconds a `:work` message is sent. You are not telling us what the `handle_info/2` is supposed to do when the message is dispatched.

Once this is defined, you can definitely write a test to assert that a message has been received by using the `assert_received` assertion.

Comment: Hi @bruno-ripa, thanks for answering. I've updated my question by adding to it some code :)

Comment: So, assuming that `do_smt()` isn't relevant, you are not _spawning_ any new process. It's always the same process that does something and _schedules_ a message to be sent every @interval. Still my answer is valid; you have several ways to test this. You can decide to test the message being received with `assert_received` or maybe you can test that effect of `do_smt()` is in place ?

Comment: `do_smt()` spawns new processes with `Task.start(fn -> do_stm_else() end)` and this I want to test in other test. Could you please tell me how can I test both?

Answer (score 1):

I would test `do_smt()` by using [Mock library](https://github.com/jjh42/mock) and writing a test that makes as assertion like the following:

```
with_mock(MyModule, [do_stm_else: fn -> :ok]) do
   do_smt()

   assert_called MyModule.do_stm_else()
end
```

In this way, you have called the function that the task should execute, so you can assume that the task creation is being called.

If you want to let the `do_stm_else` function communicate with your test (in this scenario it looks a bit overengineered) you should:

1. get the pid of the test by calling `self()`
2. Pass the pid to the mock function to get it used
3. use `assert_receive` to verify that the communication has occurred

```
pid = self()

with_mock(MyModule, [do_stm_else: fn -> 
      Process.send(pid, :msg)
   ]) do
   do_smt()

   assert_called MyModule.do_stm_else()
end

assert_receive(:msg)
```

Please note that I had no time to check this, you should spend a bit to investigate.